# Compile the Sass locally,

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I’ve just got to grips with SASS and Compass and have been using it locally. Is there a simpler way of uploading the files online though? My natural instinct is to edit live files but it just doesn’t work with SASS.

How do people go about updating their live css files?

Comment: editing live files, as in via the browser? - (auto updating your scss files from local to production?) - please be more explicit about what you're asking

Comment: via FTP, I am using brackets editor for live css file edit

Comment: brackets-sass? (however you should probably have a workflow as such
`develop on local` **>** `push to repo` **>** `CI/CD production`; (listen to webhooks for `git repo`, otherwise you'd have to manage discrepancies between versions;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best set-up for doing Sass changes is to have a local environment that mimics your production environment. With a local environment you can keep Compass running as you make Sass changes, and you just need to refresh your local to see changes.

When you're happy with your changes, upload your compiled CSS to the server.

I'm sure there *are* ways to write and compile Sass on the server, but at that you're also introducing an easy way to blow up your site if you get a compiling error.

Depending on what your live environment is (static HTML pages, WordPress, Magento, etc.) there are different local environments that work best.

Static pages - You should be able to just work out of the browser with a set of files

WordPress - I prefer using Brad Parbs' [Variable VVV](https://github.com/bradp/vv)

Magento - I prefer setting up [Magento through MAMP](http://www.woolleydesign.net/2011/05/installing-magento-on-a-mac-mamp-server/)

Comment: I am using sass in WordPress